# Can answers have a "copy link" button/link?

Tags: support, sharing

Sometimes I don't want to refer to another question but to an answer on which I am building my solution upon. However, I am missing a "*copy link*" option where a link to the answer is copied to the clipboard to not just refer to a question but instead to a particular answer of a question.

Wouldn't it make sense to have that?

Comment: I don't like that it takes a minimum of two clicks to do it, but that functionality already exists. How you access it depends on your interface (full site, mobile site, app) and platform (browser, OS), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean this?

[image]

Click on the "share" link beneath any answer, and you get a popup with a direct link to the answer. Then just press Ctrl+C and you have the link saved to your clipboard. Done.

As @JF mentions, you can also *right*-click on the "share" link and press "Copy Link Address" to get the link on your clipboard.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that.. :D yeah that was actually what I meant. case closed.

Comment: You can also right-click the “share” link and choose “Copy Link Address” (or similar) from the pop up menu.